# What kind of basking areas exist for turtles?

Tags: containment, turtles, lighting, habitat

I want to build my turtle a basking area.

What areas exist? And what are their advantages and disadvantages?

(I would favor one answer per kind of basking area.)

Answer (score 2):

### DIY hanging kind of cage

[image: turtle in basking area]

A cage from egg-crate-grid is resting onto two bent pipes. The pipes are hooked onto the tank's edges. The pipes are secured with screws to not disconnect. The cage holds together with some zip ties, also the cage is fixed with some of them onto the pipes.

(I did not get any egg-crate-grid in Germany; because of this I used some kind of car's radiator grill out of plastics. Some advantage: it tolerates higher temperatures from the basking light bulb.)

*Disadvantages:*

- Only suitable for male turtles (or females need an additional box to lay eggs)
- Suitable for one turtle only (it could become a trap for the second one in case of disagreements)
- Not the best looking solution
- Needs some manual-craft-gifted-hands

*Advantages:*

- One can build it relatively cheaply and easy.
- They are also available to buy
- One does not need any additional space beneath the tank
- The turtle cannot fall out of the tank
- The water height can be quite high, compared to other solutions
- Size of water area is not compromised

Comment: related:[What is "egg crate" for a turtles basking area?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28751/what-does-eggcrate-mean-in-the-context-of-a-material-for-a-turtle-basking-area?rq=1)